# OpenCV Flann index save and load does not work

Tags: opencv, flann

I am trying this simple test to check if I can store prepopulated indices to file and load them at later times. The saved and loaded mats are different. Also, knnSearch throws segfaults during the matching. I am seeing this issue only when using LSHIndexParams (for binary features).

```
void flannSaveAndLoadTest(Mat descriptor) {
    // construct an index
   flann::LshIndexParams lshIndexParams(20,10,2);
   flann::Index kdtree(descriptor, lshIndexParams, cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);

   // save descriptors to file
   writeMatToFile(descriptor, "before_index_save.dat");

   // save index to file
   kdtree.save("index.dat");

   // load index from file
   Mat mat = Mat(descriptor.rows, descriptor.cols, CV_8UC1);
   flann::Index kdtree1(mat, flann::SavedIndexParams("index.dat"), cvflann::FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);

   // save loaded mat
   writeMatToFile(mat, "after_index_save.dat");

   // search in this tree
   Mat dists = Mat(descriptor.rows, 2, CV_32S);
   Mat indices = Mat(descriptor.rows, 3, CV_32S);
   kdtree1.knnSearch(descriptor, indices, dists, 2);

}
```

before_index_save:

```
%YAML:1.0
mat: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 60
   cols: 32
   dt: u
   data: [ 10, 157, 16, 137, 81, 214, 178, 39, 45, 5, 74, 1, 172, 30, 38,
       196, 144, 59, 131, 33, 84, 152, 17, 223, 39, 52, 10, 67, 18, 6,
       141, 206, 11, 91, 50, 141, 119, 86, 190, 48, 45, 76, 94, 167, 236,
       30, 183, 228, 246, 125, 151, 231, 197, 144, 49, 236, 39, 125, 138,
       131, 14, 63, 61, 223, 15, 95, 35, 135, 119, 30, 190, 168, 45, 232,
       91, 231, 204, 94, 159, 228, 246, 93, 147, 231, 197, 144, 125, 238,
       38, 60, 143, 135, 14, 55, 57, 213, 10, 149, 16, 129, 81, 214, 178,
       39, 45, 5, 74, 1, 172, 30, 6, 196, 144, 27, 131, 33, 22, 152, 17,
       207, 39, 52, 10, 67, 18, 6, 141, 206, 124, 236, 196, 30, 137, 161,
       70, 207, 210, 179, 169, 24, 99, 225, 105, 158, 9, 226, 104, 26,
       58, 111, 142, 51, 184, 134, 85, 124, 243, 123, 210, 8, 10, 0, 16,
       129, 81, 214, 176, 3, 45, 5, 66, 1, 140, 30, 38, 196, 128, 25,
       131, 1, 4, 152, 17, 196, 7, 20, 26, 67, 2, 4, 13, 206, 244, 172,
       157, 122, 137, 237, 69, 206, 210, 179, 161, 24, 115, 241, 73, 27,
       9, 226, 104, 26, 58, 111, 218, 51, 217, 131, 85, 124, 240, 121,
       198, 34, 197, 36, 157, 103, 128, 46, 103, 184, 112, 162, 43, 88,
       215, 115, 9, 123, 17, 68, 104, 106, 49, 212, 217, 10, 237, 166,
       101, 20, 192, 115, 2, 32, 252, 188, 189, 118, 137, 124, 85, 158,
       179, 247, 166, 24, 223, 247, 75, 59, 129, 214, 236, 26, 56, 103,
       251, 32, 219, 251, 85, 63, 194, 113, 198, 114, 196, 64, 157, 39,
       1, 78, 38, 8, 40, 178, 35, 8, 214, 115, 73, 27, 144, 84, 104, 98,
       96, 212, 217, 8, 197, 178, 65, 20, 0, 115, 3, 34, 11, 91, 50, 141,
       119, 86, 191, 48, 13, 76, 94, 167, 236, 30, 183, 228, 246, 125,
```

after_index_save:

```
%YAML:1.0
mat: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 60
   cols: 32
   dt: u
   data: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 110, 100, 101,
       120, 95, 115, 97, 118, 101, 46, 100, 97, 116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 241, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 152, 169, 51, 241, 97, 127,
       0, 0, 152, 169, 51, 241, 97, 127, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 98, 101, 102,
       111, 114, 101, 95, 105, 110, 100, 101, 120, 95, 115, 97, 118, 101,
       46, 100, 97, 116, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       176, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 192, 188, 45, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

Comment: Linked discussion: http://answers.opencv.org/question/34180/flann-descriptor-save-and-load-doesnt-work/

Comment: I was just trying to save-load an index (using different index parameters tho) -- and in order to load the index from a file, I also had to load the database descriptors again (not just give it an empty matrix of the right size as you did). The only thing it saved on (I think) was the index build time. If you think this will help, I can post what I did in my code (but agian, different params).